# Finding maximal chains in an ordered set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $R$={$((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))$:$x_1\le x_2, y_1\le y_2$} 
find the maximal chaings.

Could it be that every maximal chains is of the form {$(a,b)+t(1,1)|t\in\Bbb{R}$} such that every other chain of the form {$n(a,b)+m(1,1)|m\in\Bbb{R}$}is the same one? I would appreciate your help...

Comment: What is the domain of $R$?

Comment: I forgot to add it, I am sorry... The domain is $\Bbb{R}^{2}$

Comment: What about $\{(x,0)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$ is this a maximal chain? What about $\{(x,e^x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$? I don't see an immediate "nice" description, but I can easily imagine writing this exercise thinking that there is one.

Comment: Why would someone downvote my question... It is a question.
I didn't understand, are they a maximal chain?